# How to convert a non-convex problem to a convex problem?

Tags: convex-analysis, cvxpy

I am a graduate student just learned the convex optimization. I am solving a problem about convex using cvxpy. However when I structured the problem and used the solver model the compiler told me it was not a DCP problem.I just realized it was a non-convex problem. I came here to ask if this problem can be converted to a convex problem. 
The problem description goes: I wanna optimize the sum of 3 bit rates, the bit rate forum goes like this: $R_i = \alpha_iW_ilog(1+\beta_iP_i/W_i)$,inside $P_i$ and $W_i$ are variable , $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are constant(different for 3 cases).The 6 parameters are $\alpha_1 = 2$,$\alpha_2 = 2.4$,$\alpha_3 = 2.8$ and $\beta_1 = 2$,$\beta_2 = 2.4$,$\beta_3 = 2.8$. What is more there are 2 contraints: $\sum P_i = 0.5$ and $\sum W_i = 1$. The problem is how to allocate $P_i$and $W_i$ to maximize the $\sum _1 ^ 3R_i$. 
I firstly tried to structured the problem into cvxpy and solved, the code goes like this:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

def bit_rate(alpha, beta, p, w):

    return alpha * w * cp.log(1 + beta * p / w)

# Create scalar optimization variables.
p_1 = cp.Variable()
p_2 = cp.Variable()
p_3 = cp.Variable()
w_1 = cp.Variable()
w_2 = cp.Variable()
w_3 = cp.Variable()

r_1 = bit_rate(2, 2, p_1, w_1) 
r_2 = bit_rate(2.4, 2.4, p_2, w_2) 
r_3 = bit_rate(2.8, 2.8, p_3, w_3) 

# Create  constraints.
constraints = [p_1 + p_2 + p_3 == 0.5,
               w_1 + w_2 + w_3 == 1,
               p_1 >= 0, p_2 >= 0, p_3 >= 0,
               w_1 >= 0, w_2 >= 0, w_3 >= 0]

# Form objective.
obj = cp.Maximize(r_1 + r_2 + r_3)

# Form and solve problem.
prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
prob.solve()  # Returns the optimal value.
print("status:", prob.status)
print("optimal value", prob.value)
print("p optimal var", p_1.value, p_2.value, p_3.value)
print("W optimal var", w_1.value, w_2.value, w_3.value)
```

But it turned out the bug

```
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
2.0 * var0 / var3
2.4 * var1 / var4
2.8 * var2 / var5
```

I figured it out that the $P_i/W_i$ is the problem, it is not convex, So I came to ask if this problem can be converted to a convex optimization problem and use cvxpy to solve.Thanks for attention!

Comment: Oh yes, I have changed the description. In the code I am trying to maximize the $R_i$

Comment: Is $W_i$ restricted to be positive?

Comment: Thanks for the exact answer and reference! Yeah $W_i$ is positive.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but it's too long for a comment. I think it will be more clear if you write your optimization problem like this:

\begin{align}
\text{maximize} & \quad \sum_{i=1}^3 \alpha_i W_i \log(1+\beta_iP_i/W_i) \\
\text{subject to} & \quad \sum_{i=1}^3 P_i = 1/2, \\
& \quad \sum_{i=1}^3 W_i = 1.
\end{align}
The optimization variables are the real numbers $P_i, W_i$ (for $i = 1, 2, 3$). The values of the parameters $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are $\alpha_1 = 2, \alpha_2 = 2.4, \alpha_3 = 2.8$ and $\beta_1 = 2, \beta_2 = 2.4, \beta_3 = 2$.

To recognize this problem as convex, it seems helpful to note that the function 
$$
f(P,W) = \begin{cases} - W \log(1 + \beta_i P/W) & \quad \text{if } W > 0, 1 + \beta_i P/W > 0\\
\infty & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is the perspective of the convex function
$$
g(x) = -\log(1 + \beta_i x).
$$
(See section 3.2.6, p. 89 of [Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/).) But I need to think more carefully about whether $W$ is restricted to be positive.

Comment: Thanks! So seemingly can I regard P/W as a integrated variable? What about the front multiply factor $W_i$? Plus the P and W are both variable.

Comment: I have read the textbook, do you mean the convexity of $g(x)$ and $f(P, W)$ are equal, which means they can get the maximize objective at the same $x/(P/W)$ ?

Comment: The function $f$ that I wrote down is convex, and if you write your optimization problem as a minimization problem rather than a maximization problem, it almost looks equivalent to minimizing $\sum_i f(P_i, W_i)$ subject to the constraints you listed. Maybe it is fully equivalent, since you mentioned in a comment that $W_i$ is restricted to be positive (which is something you should state explicitly when writing your optimization problem).

Comment: Thanks, I reviewed the problem description, it said $P_i$ and $W_i$ are both non-negative. But I also have to convert the constraints of $\sum P_i$ and $\sum W_i$ due to the variable transformation.